# Asymptotic Prediction Interval from Central Limit Theorem for Renewal Processes

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference

It is a well known result that for the counting process $\{N(t), t \geq 0 \}$ associated with a renewal process $\{S_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ we have the central limit theorem

\begin{equation*}
\frac{N(t) - \frac{t}{\mu}}{\sigma \sqrt{t}\mu^{-\frac{3}{2}}} \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0,1) \text{ as } t \rightarrow \infty
\end{equation*}
where $0 < \mu < \infty$ is the expected value of the interarrival times $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $0 < \sigma^2 < \infty$ is their variance.

From this I would like to derive an asymptotic prediction interval for $N(t)$. From the above result it is clear that
\begin{equation*}
P(\frac{t}{\mu} - z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sigma \mu^{-\frac{3}{2}} \sqrt{t} \leq N(t) \leq \frac{t}{\mu} + z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sigma \mu^{-\frac{3}{2}} \sqrt{t}) \overset{t \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 1-\alpha,
\end{equation*}
which gives me such an interval. However in my case I do not know $\mu$, nor $\sigma$. I can use consistent estimators $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ and apply Slutsky's Theorem to get
\begin{equation*}
\frac{N(t) - \frac{t}{\mu}}{\hat{\sigma} \sqrt{t} \hat{\mu}^{-\frac{3}{2}}} \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0,1) \text{ as } t \rightarrow \infty
\end{equation*}
but I do not know how to get rid of the $\mu$ in the numerator. Has anybody got any suggestions?

Comment: Why isn't it possible to just insert $\hat{\mu}$ in your equation?

Comment: @StanTendijck Well $\mu$ is a real number whereas $\hat{\mu}$ is a random variable. For the estimators in the denominator this works because if the estimators are consistent then $\frac{\sigma \mu^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{\hat{\sigma} \hat{\mu}^{-\frac{3}{2}}} \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} 1$. I can then multiply the original expression with this fraction and apply Slutsky's Theorem. The actual parameters cancel out and the estimators remain.

Comment: But using Slutsky's theorem I think you should be able to do this. Also note that if $X_n \stackrel{P}{\to} c$, then $X_n^{-1}\stackrel{P}{\to}  c^{-1}$ provided $c\neq 0$.

Comment: @StanTendijck I understand the last part, I essentially already used that when multiplying with $\frac{\sigma \mu^{-3/2}}{\hat{\sigma} \hat{\mu}^{-3/2}}$. My intuition also tells me that this should work out, but I am unable to write down a rigorous argument. I essentially have to show that $\frac{N(t) - \frac{t}{\hat{\mu}}}{N(t) - \frac{t}{\mu}} \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} 1$, then I could use the same argument as before.

Comment: Ah I see what the problem is, so I think that it depends on the rate of convergence of $\hat\mu\to\mu$ with respect to $N(t) \to t/\mu$. I can't help you immediately because it's time to sleep where I live. Can you maybe give the definition of $\hat{\mu}$ and the order of convergence, then we probably can work with that.

Comment: @StanTendijck I do not necessarily know the rate of convergence, but I guess if I choose $\hat{\mu} = \bar{X}_n$ then the WLLN gives me $\hat{\mu} = \mu + o_P(1)$. I also know from another result that $\frac{N(t)}{t} = \frac{1}{\mu} + o_P(1)$ if that helps.

Comment: This is a bit of a side point, but as $N$ is a counting process my assumption would have been that you would be interested in a one-sided confidence interval, which would then be $[0,\frac{t}{\hat{\mu}} + z_{1-\alpha}\sqrt{t}\hat{\sigma}\hat{\mu}^{-3/2} )$ if the validity of using estimators can be established.